# Yarn Syntax error on Ubuntu 16 at yarn --version

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, yarnpkg

I installed Yarn on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Setup flow:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

Apparently it doesn't end with an error:

```
...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
```

But when I run `yarn --version` I get this error

```
root@AMS-148750:~# yarn --version
/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:46083
  let {
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/yarn/bin/yarn.js:24:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Please let me know how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would assume that your nodejs version is too old for the version of yarn you installed. Check the requirements for your yarn version and see if your server fulfills them.

Comment: You were right. Thanks ;) Write your comment as an answer to can mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a too old nodejs version for the version of yarn installed from the repo. Please check the requirements for the yarn version you installed and make sure your server fulfills them.

Answer (score 3):

that is because your node version is incompatible with yarn.Check your node version with `node -version` if you have an older version of node then upgrade it to latest version by using: 
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs`

Answer (score 1):

There could be another reason for that. Your nodejs version is very old. You just need to upgrade your nodejs with below command (using npm).

```
sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable
```

This will upgrade to latest stable version.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got such error because I'm using `nvm` but I didn't install any node version :stuck_out_tongue_closed_eyes: 
`nvm list`

```
N/A
iojs -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
```

Just install node version which you need, for example
`nvm install 13.3.0`